# Add custom context to Login Page Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

**Scenario**

I want to build my own IDP. I need to pass custom parameters from my client apps to my IDP. I use Asp Net Core 3.1 in both Client and IDP (IS4). I have started from this pluralsight repo code [KevinDockx pluralisght gitrepo](https://github.com/KevinDockx/DealingWithCredentialsWhenSecuringAspNetCore3)

**Try**

From here: [developers.de](https://developers.de/2019/11/29/how-to-pass-custom-parameters-in/) and [jerriepelser](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/adding-parameters-to-openid-connect-authorization-url/) I know that it is enought to add to my Client Startup Open Id Configuration additional section for events:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {...})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>{...})
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:44318/";
    options.ClientId = "imagegalleryclient";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.Scope.Add("address");
    options.Scope.Add("imagegalleryapi");
    options.Scope.Add("country");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");
    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("idp");
    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("s_hash");
    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("auth_time");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("country", "country");
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.GivenName,
        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
    };
    // events section
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("shopId", "123");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});
```

In Get Login Action in my IDP i would like to read value for *shopId* - *123*:

```
var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
string shopId = context.Parameters["shopId"];
```

**Problem**

The problem is that there is no shopId in returnUlr or/and context.Parameters at all.

Comment: Would you share IdentityServer logs during your authentication?

Comment: Problem solved i will post answer later. The problem was that client's code was overriding events property